# Requests for site not hosted on my server

Tags: apache, linux, apache-log-files, httpd

I am seeing http get requests in my servers access log for a site that is not hosted on my server and also the dns records of the site do not point to my server the domain points to 3 ip addresses in china. Anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: This is most probably some spam bot.

Comment: It is possible that it is a proxy test. It is not uncommon that forged packets be addressed to your server hoping to proxy to another server. At one point, I had over 100,000 forged proxy attempts from China. This went on for months without success of course. It is not uncommon that Trojans are used for this purpose so the requests do not actually have to come from China or be addressed to China to be Chinese hackers. It is just a possibility. Something to think about and research.